# Java, select text Exactly in JEditorPane

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans, jeditorpane

I'm using `jEditorPane` to act kinda as some editor, the one who asked for this of me, also needed a find replace search... so I wanted to let him select in find and then do replace on need.

so I provide this simple code:

```
private void jButton5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    int start = (jEditorPane1.getSelectionStart()>jEditorPane1.getSelectionEnd())?jEditorPane1.getSelectionEnd():jEditorPane1.getSelectionStart();

    int max = (start>jEditorPane1.getSelectionStart())?start:jEditorPane1.getSelectionStart();

    String searchWord = jTextField3.getText();
    int searchIndex = jEditorPane1.getText().indexOf(searchWord, max);
    if(searchIndex != -1){
        jEditorPane1.select(searchIndex, searchIndex+searchWord.length());
    }
    else{
        jEditorPane1.setSelectionStart(-1);
        jEditorPane1.setSelectionEnd(-1);
    }
}
```

fortunatelly the application return good indexes, but unfortunatelly on view windows I see no selection.

I'm also new to java, please help

---

PS. buttons action are provided by netbeans itself

---

THe sample you requested

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/*
 * test.java
 *
 * Created on Jun 12, 2013, 8:23:19 PM
 */
package wordchecker;

/**
 *
 * @author Hassan
 */
public class test extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /** Creates new form test */
    public test() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /** This method is called from within the constructor to
     * initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
     * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTextPane1 = new javax.swing.JTextPane();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextPane1);

        jTextField1.setText("jTextField1");

        jButton1.setText("jButton1");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(24, 24, 24)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addComponent(jButton1))
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 366, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 234, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jButton1))
                .addContainerGap(14, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        int startFrom = jTextPane1.getSelectionStart();
        if(jTextPane1.getSelectionStart() == jTextPane1.getSelectionEnd()){
            startFrom = -1;
        }

        String searchWord = jTextField1.getText();
        int searchIndex = jTextPane1.getText().indexOf(searchWord, startFrom);
        if(searchIndex != -1){
            jTextPane1.select(searchIndex, searchIndex+searchWord.length());
        }
        else{
            jTextPane1.setSelectionStart(0);
            jTextPane1.setSelectionEnd(0);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new test().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextPane jTextPane1;
    // End of variables declaration
}
```

Comment: `i'm uning jEditorPane to act kinda as some editor` - don't use a JEditorPane. It is designed to display HTML. Instead use a JTextPane so you don't need to worry about HTML. Post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: i use plain text, but i also test that

Comment: i change it to jTextPane, but again it didnt worked....
i post full class in an answer, seem here i'm limit to post

Comment: I did not ask for your full class. I asked for a SSCCE. A SSCCE would contain your text pane (for your text), a text field (for the search text) and a button (to select the search text in the text pane). We don't have time to read through all that code.

Comment: ok, i make it, and you are right, my time is limit, i make a new net beans frame and send it in here (replace last codes)

Comment: i add the SSCCE you requested, the time i enter that site, i though it let me make sample there and compile it, so once i didnt find any tools to compile, or entry for text, it put full code here, sry for that, also low speed network we have here, add to the stress :'(

Comment: can you stop editing, and do some help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selection of a text component is only displayed when the text component has focus. When you click on the button it gains focus so you don't see the text selection. You could make the button non-focusable or you can add the following to the bottom of your actionPerformed() method:

```
jTextPane1.requestFocusInWindow();
```

Also, don't use the getText() method. This will cause problems with offsets.

```
int searchIndex = jTextPane1.getText().indexOf(searchWord, startFrom);
```

See [Text and New Lines](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/02/07/text-and-new-lines/) for more information and a solution. The basics of this link is to use:

```
int length = textPane.getDocument().getLength();
String text = textPane.getDocument().getText(0, length);
```

The above will only return "\n" as the EOL string so the offsets will match when you do a search and then select the text.

Edit:

I generally use code like the following:

```
int startFrom = jTextPane1.getCaretPosition();
```

Comment: thanks man, i though u left so i went tried other things hoping it work, like mix of highlighter and caret, but since it process \n and other escape as 2 char, they didnt match :|

one more question, i done request focus, and non-focusable you told me, but still my selection dont move to next find position :'(

what u think i miss?

Comment: i mark this as answer already, and go try other options, but i hope u still would like to take a look :* thank you

Comment: `i though u left` - yes, we all have other things to do. That is why you should always post a proper SSCCE with the original question so you can get a complete answer right away when we have free time. You never know when we will have free time again. `but still my selection dont move to next find position` - see my edit.

Comment: man, my access to provided site is limit, and i cant enter due to my country filtering center...
i hope u can help me once more :
once i use following (next message) block of code, my selection goes to wrong place, doe to escape character and some time unknown things, it dont select the one it should, can you give me direct tipe / copy pasted tip, in here?

Comment: `String text = jEditorPane1.getText();
int start = jEditorPane1.getSelectionStart();
int end = jEditorPane1.getSelectionEnd();
if((start != -1) && (end != -1)){
    if(start != end){
        if(start>end){
            int temp = start;
            start = end;
            end = temp;
        }
        String firstPart = text.substring(0, start);
        String secondPart = text.substring(end+1, text.length()-1);

        String removedSelection = firstPart + secondPart;
        jEditorPane1.setText(removedSelection);
    }
}`

Comment: I added the basic code to get the text from the Document (not the text pane) from the tip which should help make sure you select the correct text.

Comment: Document? i see every one talk about document, i try to get text from it, if it have any clear method, i put result in here, also for lating, i made new topic, it's good you answer there then
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17073304/selection-indexes-are-not-same-to-gettext-indexes