# Selection Indexes are not same to getText indexes

Tags: java, string, swing, document, jeditorpane

i'm new to java, start a project 7 days ago, today with some folks from this place i successed to pass through one problem, but still there's one more...

in last problem i needed to search an string and highlight it, but now, my problem is:

Why selection index are not same to the indexes i search for after some unknown character which i dont know my self :|

this is my button code:

```
    int startFrom = jEditorPane1.getSelectionStart();
    if(jEditorPane1.getSelectionStart() == jEditorPane1.getSelectionEnd()){
        startFrom = -1;
    }

    String searchWord = jTextField3.getText();
    int searchIndex = jEditorPane1.getText().indexOf(searchWord, startFrom + 1);
    if(searchIndex != -1){
        jEditorPane1.requestFocusInWindow();
        jEditorPane1.select(searchIndex, searchIndex+searchWord.length());
    }
    else{
        jEditorPane1.setSelectionStart(0);
        jEditorPane1.setSelectionEnd(0);
    }
```

and i'm sure that i need to do some string processing, to convert string index to swing jEditorPane/JTextPane index

for example:
i search for do in string like this: 
"Hey,
How do you do?"

and it highlight it this way:
"Hey,
How d`o`you do?"

which mean it started one index forther that what it should, and in here it's casue escape char of \n and i dont know, cause some time it happen in single row text...

how can i get ride of this?

Comment: Did you not learn anything from your last posting? You have been asked to post a SSCCE with the original question. We do not have time to sit around waiting for you to post a SSCCE. I only know the answer because I answered the last questions. Others reading this question do not know the context of your question. Also, since you are using a JTextPane, name your variables apporopriately so the posted code doesn't mislead us. The behaviour of a JEditorPane and JTextPane may be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Text and New Lines](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/02/07/text-and-new-lines/) for more information and a solution. The basics of this link is to use:

```
int length = textPane.getDocument().getLength();
String text = textPane.getDocument().getText(0, length);
```

The above will only return "\n" as the EOL string so the offsets will match when you do a search and then select the text.

Comment: ah, thanks again, if i werent in a limit country, and had some global account, i surly wished to pay you half, cause you didnt just saved my work, but also my reputation, i took our university price for the competetion, and student know me as good coder, and it was bad for me.

surly i'm nothing :D

Comment: if i had new this before, i could make take advantage of HTML to make highlighter, i told him i cant do that :))

Comment: JTextPane supports highlighting and it is much easier to use than playing with HTML.

Comment: the time i start, i just look through tooltips on netbean with no knowledge, and start writing, like what i knows from C#, i faced many new thing i never faced before, though once more i worked with java gui environment. why java have things like this? what are they?
`new [Class Name].[Something]();`? is nested class?
and one more , when we implement mysqlConnection with
class.forName(...), we dont store it, where it goes ?